# If A is a subset of a topological space, then $Bd(A) \subseteq Cl(A)$. Prove using elements/ sets.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

If A is a subset of a topological space, then $Bd(A) \subseteq Cl(A)$. Prove.

I know this statement is true.  I am now trying to prove it.  I am in a basic topology class and to do a lot of set proofs we start by letting an element be included in one side and show it is in the other.

I was given the hint to use this fact $Cl(A)= A \cup Bd(A)$.  However I have to prove that statement first.  For this statement I started with Let $x \in Cl(A)$ then by defintion of closure $x \in A$ since the closure is the smallest closed set containing $A$ and therefore $x \in A \cup Bd(A)$.
Now let $x \in  A \cup Bd(A)$. How do I show $x \in$ the $Cl(A)$ and then use that prove my first statement?

Comment: Did you take a Set Theory class before diving into topology?

Comment: How do you define $Bd(A)$ (I guess it is the *border* of $A$)?

Comment: What is your definition of boundary? I usually see the boundary defined as the intersection of the closure of $A$ and the closure of the complement of $A$ or something equivalent.

Comment: Another (equivalent) definition of the boundary is $\partial A=\overline{A}\setminus A^\circ$ (where $\partial A$ is the boundary, $\overline{A}$ is the closure, and $A^\circ$ the interior).  With this definition the result in question is trivial.

Comment: Our introduction to topology book chapter 1 was set theory while chapter 2 was a basic introduction to topology

Comment: My definition of boundary is "Let $(X, \mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and let $A \subseteq X$ .  The boundary of A is the set of all points $x \in X$ for which every open set containing $x$ intersects both $A$ and $X-A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the hint. If you are allowed to assume it, the question is trivial, but proving it is equivalent to proving the problem...

Let $x\in Bd(A)$. Then by definition,  every open set containing $x$ intersects both $A$ and $X−A$.

If $x\notin Cl(A)$, then there exist on open set, namely $U = X-Cl(A)$, containing $x$ such that $U\cap A = \emptyset$.

We can see this since $A\subset Cl(A)$.

But this contradicts the definition of $x\in Bd(A)$, so we get that $x\in Cl(A)$.

Thus, $Bd(A)\subset Cl(A)$.

Comment: I think we were supposed to prove the hint in order to use it to prove the statement.

Comment: Right, but your approach of showing $A\cup Bd(A) \subset Cl(A)$ forces you to show $Bd(A)\subset Cl(A)$. So proving your hint is actually more work...

Comment: I can see that now...

Comment: Does this argument make sense?

Comment: Yes but I have never proved that $A \subset Cl(A)$ so I think I would either need to prove that or use something else.

Comment: That one should follow from the definiton of $Cl(A)$ as the smallest closed set  containing $A$.